# Facebook long live tokens - pointless?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need help with understanding some of the FB token logic.
I have a Powershell script that posts stuff on one of my Facebook Pages.

I pulled a "never expire" token for my page using the Access Token Debugger [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken).

It worked fine for the most part but sometime later it was invalidated because I logged out of FB. What is the point of this if I must get an Access Token each and every time and extend it each and every time?

Comment: It should not get invalidated when you just log out of Facebook AFAIK, but when you change the password of the user access that created it.

Comment: But that's exactly what happens. I keep getting "Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out". And it does not matter if I log back in later.

Comment: How exactly did you create the token? Did you follow the instructions in the documentation step by step?